# Strings containing an accent do not appear

Tags: r, utf-8, shiny, multilingual

I'm currently building a shiny application that needs to be translated in different languages. I have the whole structure but I'm struggling into getting values such as "Validació" that contain accents.

The structure I've followed is the following:

- I have a dictionary that is simply a csv with the translation where
  there's a key and then each language. The structure of this dictionary is the following:

> ```
> key, cat, en
> "selecció", "selecció", "Selection"
> "Diferències","Diferències", "Differences"
> "Descarregar","Descarregar", "Download"
> "Diagnòstics","Diagnòstics", "Diagnoses"
> ```

---

- I have a script that once the dictionary.csv is modified, generates a .bin file that later will be loaded in the code.

---

- In strings.R I have all the strings that will appear on the code and I use a function to translate the current language to the one I want. The function is the following:

Code:

```
tr <- function(text){    
  sapply(text, function(s) translation[[s]][["cat"]], USE.NAMES=F) 
}
```

When I translate something, since I am doing in another file, I assign it to another variable something like:

```
str_seleccio <- tr('Selecció)
```

---

- The problem I'm facing is that for example if we translate `'Selecció'` would be according to this function, `tr('Selecció')` and provides a correct answer if I execute it in the RStudio terminal but when I do it in the Shiny application, appears to me as a `NULL`. If the word I translate has no accents such as "Hello", `tr("Hello")` provides me a correct answer in the Shiny application and I can see it throught the code.

So mainly tr(word) gets the correct value but when assigning it "loses the value" so I'm a bit lost how to do it.

I know that you can do something like `Encoding(str_seleccio) <- "UTF-8"` but in this case is not working. In case of plain words it used to do but since when I asssign it, gets `NULL` is not working.

Any idea? Any suggestion? What I would like is to add something to `tr function`

The main idea comes from this repository that if you can take a look is the simplest version you can do, but (s)he has problem with utf-8 also.

https://github.com/chrislad/multilingualShinyApp

Comment: Have you looked at the `fileEncoding` and `encoding` arguments to `read.csv`? You might also find this link helpful: http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Comment: Currently I read using  encoding = "UTF-8" argument when using read.csv. I'll take a look to the link you've send me now. Thank you!

Comment: Could you check the bytes used to encode the accents? Accent encoding is not unique, if you used two different editors, such accent could be encoded differently (as one code, as two code: character with combining accent)

Comment: Have you looked here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/unicode-characters.html and http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html suggested (re)save all files with UTF-8 encoding.

Additionaly change within `updateTranslation.R`:

```
translationContent <- read.delim("dictionary.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", as.is = TRUE)
```

to:

`translationContent <- read.delim("dictionary.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", as.is = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`.

Warning, when you (re)save ui.R, your "c-cedilla" might get destroyed. Just re-insert it, in case it happens.

Happy easter :)